# Parsley: How NOT to validate on certain events

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, parsley.js, parsley

I want to trigger the parsley-error on an input text field only at the time of 'focus out' and not on change event.

These are the steps I perform to produce the issue:

1. Enter some invalid characters in the text field. At this point of
   time, the parsley-error is not trigerred (OK, as per my
   requirements).
2. When I tab-out of the field, the parsley-error is trigerred and I
   see the error on the tooltip of the text box (OK, as per my
   requirements).
3. Now, when I again go back to the same text field and start entering
   some more characters, the parsley error is trigerred (This is the
   ISSUE).

I don't want the user to be bugged by the error appearing on the tooltip while he is making the changes. The error should be appeared only at the time of focus out but on this third step, the error is appearing at the time of 'change' as well.

**I am not sure how can I tell Parsley to avoid some certain triggers!**
**Any suggestion?**

Please note that the issue is not faced on the first step. The issue is faced only at the 3rd step mentioned above.
Here is my code:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control border-radius-6 onClickHideError"
                                        id="passport_number" name="passport_number" required=""
                                        maxlength="30"
                                        placeholder=""
                                        data-parsley-password-field="true"
                                        data-parsley-trigger="focusout"
                                        data-parsley-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/"
                                        data-parsley-required-message="${commonRequiredMsg}"
                                        data-parsley-pattern-message="${passportInvalidMsg}"
                                        autocomplete="off">
```

Answer (score 0):

Parsley allows you to set `data-parsley-trigger-after-failure` to your choosing.

Comment: When "data-parsley-trigger" didn't worked for me, I also tried "data-parsley-trigger-after-failure" in its place but that also did not worked. 

data-parsley-trigger-after-failure="focusout"